# Get values from shapeObj MapScript

Tags: mapserver, php, mapscript

**I'm using Mapserver 7.4.0-dev and MapScript PHP.**

In previous versions of MapServer and MapScript (https://mapserver.org/mapscript/php/index-5.6.html#shapeobj), I could query a shapeObj after its values. And get a key => value array with all the data fields.

Example:

```
public function __construct(\shapeObj $shape)
{
    foreach ($shape->values as $key => $value) {
        //Do something;
    }
}
```

In the new Mapserver and MapScript (https://mapserver.org/mapscript/mapscript.html#shapeobj), there is no $shape->values attribute.

I can get the value of element X but no the key name (Example "Gis_ID") by using this function:

```
$shape->getValue(3);
```

But this does not help my much. My map sources are dynamic and i need to target the data by IDs, and not a random array index.

Can anyone help me figure this out? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thanks to @interactivegis.com for answer on MS4W-mailing list**

Hi Kenneth,

The example code we sent out earlier today actually helps with this as 
well.  The IDs are now in the layer object, so after you get the $layer 
and get a shape using the layerObj Methods (like queryBy or nextShape or 
whatever from 
https://www.mapserver.org/mapscript/mapscript.html#layerobj-methods) you 
can use $layer->numitems there to see how many attribute fields the 
shapes have and loop over that using $layer->getItem($x) to get the 
names of those attribute fields.

This should let you create an array using $layer->getItem() (which I 
called $layer_headers in my sample code) which has the same numeric 
indexes as your $shape->getValue, but the $layer->getItem() values are 
the field names, so you can use a line like this to target an attribute 
directly once you've created the $layer_headers array:

$shape->getValue(array_search('Gis_ID', $layer_headers));

Depending on your needs you could loop through all of $layer->getItem() 
and all of $shape->getValue() and create an array that matches them up 
since the numerical indexes would always be a match, which is more of 
what the sample code from earlier at https://gist.github.com/andrewteg/81b8d45948d67003f5f1170e51d66e61 does.

Hope that helps!